# Jquery Accordion menu with NOT nested list

Tags: jquery, list, menu, nested, accordion

i am trying to implement a Jquery accordion menu with NOT nested list, becase i can't change my list structure.

Here my example structure:

```
<div class="accordion">
<ul id="acc-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Parent Level 1</a></li>
    <ul class="sub-menu2">
        <li><a href="#">Parent Level 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Parent Level 2</a></li>
        <ul class="sub-menu3">
            <li><a href="#">Parent Level 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent Level 3</a></li>
        </ul>
         <li><a href="#">Parent Level 2</a></li>
        <ul class="sub-menu3">
            <li><a href="#">Parent Level 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent Level 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>

    <li><a href="#">Parent Level 1</a></li>
    <ul class="sub-menu2">
        <li><a href="#">Parent Level 2</a></li>
        <ul class="sub-menu3">
            <li><a href="#">Parent Level 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent Level 3</a></li>
        </ul> 
        <li><a href="#">Parent Level 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <li><a href="#">Parent Level 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

i would like to implement something like this:
http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/nested_accordion_demo.html

this jQuery plugin works great, but ONLY with nested list.
I am not a jquery expert to modify the plugin or somthing else.

Thanks for any help

Comment: ul can only have li elements as children [http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)

Comment: It must be possible to check with javascript (jQuery) is the next html element of a <li></li> an <ul> if yes make this <li> toggle to hide and show only this next <ul> element. By the way standard this ul element is set to hidden.

Comment: it is possible but it will not be valid html, the right thing to do is to put the ul inside the li

Comment: i can rename the li and ul tags to div tags but this is also not nested but maybe easyier to implement toggle function or something similar. i have no idea how to get start